# Update the root directory of a branch from the subdirectory of another

Tags: git, github

Developing on github, I often maintain a `html/` or `_site/` subdirectory in my master branch where I generate web-based documentation for the project.  I'd like to switch to my gh-pages branch and `pull` just the contents of this `html` directory into the root of the gh-pages branch, so it will render as a nice website through github (which automatically renders html in `gh-pages` at `username.github.com/repositoryname`).  What is the best workflow to do this?

If I don't yet have the gh-pages branch set up, I can branch, clear the branch, and copy in the contents of the `html` directory and presto, I have the a site ready to go.  But I'm not sure how best to later update the gh-pages branch.

```
git branch gh-pages
git checkout gh-pages
# Remove files I don't need from the gh-pages branch
rm -rf data/ man/ R/ README.md NEWS NAMESPACE DESCRIPTION demo/
# move documentation to the root
mv inst/doc/html/* .
# remove the rest
rm -rf inst/
git add *
git commit -a -m "gh-pages documentation"
git push origin gh-pages
git checkout master
```

Now what should I do to update the gh-pages branch later?  It sounds like this might involve [subtree merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To start your gh-pages branch:

```
true | git mktree | xargs git commit-tree | xargs git branch gh-pages
```

To fetch anything you want into it, say the html directory from the master branch, read-tree and commit:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git read-tree master:html
git commit -m'gh-pages documentation'
git push origin gh-pages
git checkout master
```

and you're done.

Late addition: there's a shorter sequence for adding to the gh-pages branch:

```
git commit-tree -p gh-pages -m "" master:html \
| xargs git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages
```

which doesn't require flushing the current working tree

Comment: Would an orphan branch be equally appropriate here? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646487/starting-from-scratch-for-v2-0-should-i-keep-using-the-existing-git-repo-or-sta/7648343#7648343)

Comment: @VonC Depends on what you want.  This way your gh-pages branch keeps history, if you orphan there's no history.  The easy way to do the orphan here would be `git commit-tree v1.6:html -mreset | xargs git branch -f gh-pages`

Comment: Thanks, `read-tree` makes for a very nice solution! Definitely preferable to `git checkout master inst/doc/html` from the `gh-pages` branch and then overwriting everything.

Comment: Your first command works well but is a bit cryptic -- can you outline what it's doing and why you need to use pipes?

Comment: @cboettig I'm having a hard time getting from "a bit cryptic" to something I can help with.

Comment: After `git checkout gh-pages` and `git read-tree master:html`, I do not see any files on the branch. If I've updated the files in `master:html` `git status` gives me a list that all those files have been deleted and added, but git commit tells me that there's nothing to update!  Very confusing -- somehow I cannot get this to work again for me.

Comment: see http://paste.debian.net/171668/ for comparison.  Post your own transcript, point out where it doesn't do what you think it should  and why you think so.