# Dealing with Jekyll and Git

Tags: git, github, branch, jekyll

I use [**Jekyll**](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) with a custom [**Coderay**](http://github.com/rubychan/coderay), so I have to maintain 2 branches on GitHub

```
master; The generated HTML site
source; Markdown files, etc
```

On the `source` branch I have a `_includes` folder that I ignore because it just contains some hard links. I have a script to manage the 2 branches but it seems like there should be something better than what I have come up with.

```sh
# Start on "source" branch
jekyll /tmp
git checkout master
git stash -u # _includes
rm -r * # keeps ".git"
cp -r /tmp/* .
git add -A
git commit
git push origin master
git checkout source
git stash apply
```

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding, Is your end goal to pre-render your pages locally (with your Coderay) and then ship them to GitHub so that all it does is server them?

Comment: About the only other thing I can think to try is to create two jekyll instances. One that you use locally with your plug-ins that writes. The output of this one would be the source directory of your second one that is actually what's pushed up to git. I haven't tested that though. There are likely gotchas that will pop up. It may not be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

The better option for me was to just get rid of the hard links altogether. I did this by making a plugin that allows to render a file outside of the repo.

[**render_partial.rb**](http://github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.com/blob/source/_plugins/render_partial.rb)

```rb
module Jekyll
    class IncludeTag < Liquid::Tag
        def initialize(tag_name, file, tokens)
            super
            @file = file.strip
        end
        def render(context)
            File.read(@file)
        end
    end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('render_partial', Jekyll::IncludeTag)
```

## Option 2

This option will work if you want to keep the hard links.

[**help.github.com/ignore-files**](http://help.github.com/ignore-files)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Initial setup, configure excludes
cat > .git/info/exclude <<EOF
_includes
_site
EOF
# Commit source branch
git checkout source
git add -A
git commit -m 'new post'
git push origin source
# Commit master branch
jekyll
git checkout master
git rm -r .
cp -r _site/* .
git add -A
git commit -m 'new post'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I've been puzzling over how to maintain site files on one branch for github to display and source files on another.  Seems like there must be a better way then deleting the files each time?  There's [a solution using `git read-tree`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590156/git-update-the-root-directory-of-a-branch-from-the-subdirectory-of-another) which accomplishes the same thing you do here, though I find working with the tree directly a bit weird.  thoughts?