# What's the easiest way to deploy a folder to a branch in git?

Tags: git

I have a folder in my `master` branch named `public/`, what would be the easiest way to copy its contents to the root directory in a different branch, such as `gh-pages`?

Comment: See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616287/946850) and a [writeup](http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One really nice trick illustrated in [Generate GitHub pages in a submodule](http://blog.blindgaenger.net/generate_github_pages_in_a_submodule.html) by
[Blind Gaenger (Bernd Jünger)](http://blindgaenger.net/) is to declare a *branch* as a submodule for *another* branch!

So if your `public` content was in its own orphan branch (like `gh-pages` content is usually kept in its own orphan branch), then you could:

- declare `public` as a submodule of your main repo in `master` branch
- declare the same public as a submodule of your main repo in `gh-pages`

So any modification that you make in submodule `public` when you are in `master` branch can be updated (`git submodule update`) once you switch to `gh-pages` branch!

I am not saying this is a solution for your current setup, because it involves removing `public` from your main content, and adding it back in its own branch (ie, the other solutions might be more straightforward), but it is an interesting way to share a common directory:

```
cd yourRepo
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/public
rm .git/index
mv public ..
git clean -fdx
mv ../public/* .
git add .
git commit -m "public content in orphan branch public"
git push origin public
```

But once you have created an orphan branch to include that (`public`) content, the trick to add that branch content as a submodule for other branch is:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git submodule add -b public git@github.com:user/repo.git public
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD &lt;file&gt;..." to unstage)
#
#    new file:   .gitmodules
#    new file:   public
#
$ git commit -m "added public as submodule"
$ git push
```

And you can repeat that step for your `gh-pages` branch.

That will create a directory "`public`", present both when you checkout `master` or `gh-pages`.
In both cases (both checkout), a `git submodule update` will be enough to get back the latest evolutions done on `public` submodule.
And as usual when it comes to submodules, once you do modifications in `public` directory, make sure you are on its '`public`' branch, commit and push, then go back one directory above, and add-commit again.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So the submodule trick is no longer necessary to make both type of content visible through the same branch.

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of things based on your idea. I do like the submodule breakout! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note to self: if you had some content already versioned in `master` that you wish to use to initialize `gh-branch`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10591668/6309

Comment: A+ for keeping this answer up to date

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout --orphan branch_name
git rm -rf .
git checkout master -- public
```

Is public in the root dir of master?

Comment: Yes, `public` is in the root dir of master, however `-r` does not seem to be a known switch to `git checkout`

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r public/* ./
git add .
git stash
git checkout gh-pages
git stash apply
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a a branch based on `master`? I'd need that branch to completely be cleared and only have the `public/` content.