# Using Tower to manage a repository and gh-page branch in separate directories

Tags: git, github, git-tower

This seems like a simple thing, but cannot find the solution online. First, I know I can probably do this on the Terminal, but I would prefer to do this with [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/). Not all of my colleagues will use the Terminal. I have a repository (https://github.com/jbryer/psabook/) and I would like to use Github pages with it. I want the master branch to track the source (mostly markdown files). I build a website from those files and would like to publish that to the gh-pages branch. Can I have that as a subdirectory of my repository be tracked only for that branch?

Here's what I have tried from this post: http://blog.blindgaenger.net/generate_github_pages_in_a_submodule.html

I create a repository called psabook from Github.com. Then do the following from the command line (on a Mac if it matters):

```
mkdir foobar
cd foobar
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:jbryer/psabook.git
git push origin master
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index
git clean -fdx
echo "Hello PSA Book" > index.html
git add .
git commit -a -m "first gh-page"
git push origin gh-pages
git checkout master
git submodule add -b gh-pages git@github.com:jbryer/psabook.git _site
```

The output was:

```
Cloning into '_site'...
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 6 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Continuing...

```
git status
```

Returned:

```
On branc master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEADE <file>..." to unstage)

      new file: .gitmodules
      new file: _site
```

Continuing...

```
git commit -m "added gh-pages as submodule"
git push
```

It is this command that I get an error (note that I had to escape the parens too):

```
git submodule init
```

Submodule '_site' (git@github.com:jbryer/psagook.git) registered for path '_site'

This is the error I get:

```
error: pathspec 'Submodule' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '(git@github.com:jbryer/psabook.git)' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'registered' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'for' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'path' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

Comment: Updated to add the commands I used and the error I am getting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was the output of `git submodule add -b gh-pages git@github.com:jbryer/psabook.git _site`?

Comment: @VonC I updated with the output above. Thanks

Comment: Ok, the a `git submodule update --init` should be enough (no additional parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see both content (`master` and `gh-branch`) from the `master` branch.

You would need for that to declare your `gh-branch` as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)(!) in your `master` branch.
That way, when you are in your `master` branch, the `gh-branch` is displayed as a sub-folder.

Once that setup is done (in command line), you can manage everything from Tower.

See "[What's the easiest way to deploy a folder to a branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309)" for the submodule setup.

Each modification in `gh-branch` would then need to be committed, and you would need to go back in the main folder to commit (again), in order to record the gitlink ([special entry mode 160000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)).
That way, each version of the `master` branch knows which version of the `gh-branch` it is supposed to work with.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So this is easier now: now need for two branches, you can do everything in one.