# How to treat a folder as branch?

Tags: git

I want to create a [github page](https://pages.github.com/)

My *sites* are in the `master` branch. My actual development is in the `development` branch.

So my workflow simplified is:

```
git checkout develop
# edit & commit
gulp build-prod
# push
```

`gulp` creates a `dist` folder which contains all files which shall be in the `master` branch.

So my question is: Is it possible to treat a subfolder of my repo as a branch?
If this is not possible - what would be a good way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to treat a subfolder of my repo as a branch?

Of course, it is a well known "hack" I described a few years back in "[What's the easiest way to deploy a folder to a branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309)".

When you are in the `develop` branch, you can add your `master` branch as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, in a root folder called '`dist`':

```
git checkout develop
git submodule add -b master /url/of/your/repo.git dist
git add .
git commit -m "add dist root submodule folder as same repo, but master branch"
git push
```

Then:

```
git checkout develop
# edit & commit
gulp build-prod
cd dist
git add -A .
git commit -m "new build in master"
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "record new master state"
```

Don't forget the last 2 commands (add and commit), as they record the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) for the dist submodule.

Comment: Well this seems correct but it's not working for me right now. A bit long for a comment - tl;dr: the master branch isn't recognized as submodule and `git add [whatever]` in the dist folder just crashs git. I'll investigate it.

Comment: @Bret What OS and version of Git are you using?

Comment: @VonC Windows 10 // git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0

Comment: @Brettetete Can you try with a recent version of Git? Git 2.5 is out since yesterday: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.0.windows.1 (http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/21805)

Comment: @Brettetete keep in mind I assume the structure of the `master` branch content would match the one produced by `gulp build-prod` in dist folder.

Comment: @VonC I did. I created a complete new repository and did what you wrote. This is not working and will crash git everytime.

Comment: @Brettetete strange, I did use it without issue before.

Comment: @Brettetete what url did you use for the repo when using the `git submodule add` command?