# Does GitHub Pages allow to use a branch other than master or gh-pages?

Tags: github-pages

[GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) shows the following options for GitHub Pages:

- gh-pages branch
- master branch
- master branch /docs folder

Then can we use a branch whose name is not master or gh-pages? For example, is there any way to select a "site" branch for GitHub Pages? I tried to select the site branch in Settings, but did not see such option. So can we only use master or gh-pages? Is this documented somewhere?

<sub># I want to know this because I'm using the branch name in my site content and want to know if I need to escape the name.</sub>

Comment: Note: this is now possible, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Sept. 2020: yes actually.

> ### "[Build and deploy GitHub Pages from any branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-03-build-and-deploy-github-pages-from-any-branch/)"
>
> Repositories that use GitHub Pages can now build and deploy from any branch.
> Publishing to the special `gh-pages` branch will still work the same as it always has, but you can now choose a different branch in your repository as the publishing source.
> This functionality also removes the hardcoded dependency on user and organization pages having a `master` branch.

---

Original answer:

<del>No, those are the tow official [publication sources](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) in term of branches.</del>

The `docs` folder [could be a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309) which then might be:

- the same repository
- any branch you want

That way, publishing your pages from `docs/` could allow you to publish from any branch content.