# Is it possible to store the history of some files separately in Git?

Tags: git

There is a repository with code.

I want to store some directories and files in the repository, but so that their changes are not reflected in the development history.

For example, there is a catalog `.vscode` with VS Code settings and a file with notes `my_notes.txt`, and I want to be able to access them from different computers.

How can I make sure that the specified directories and files are saved in the repository (preferably with the history of changes), but so that their history is not mixed with the history of code development and at the same time they are available in this repository?

For example, I changed the `my_notes.txt` on one computer and then made a commit:

```
git commit my_notes.txt <some_magic>
git push <some_magic>
```

After that I want to get this file on another computer:

```
git pull <some_magic>
```

Perhaps orphaned branches are suitable for this, but I could not find how to do so I want.

If I do so:

```
echo my_notes.txt >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'update gitignore'
git checkout --orphan orhf-branch
git rm -r --cached .
rm -rf *
echo 'some text' > my_notes.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'Orphan commit'
git checkout master
```

then file `my_notes.txt` disappears from the master branch.

Is it possible to make the file `my_notes.txt` was present when I switch to the `master` branch, but the history of its changes was saved in the `orhf-branch`?
And so that I can change it in the `master` branch, but it doesn't show up as changed or untracked in `master`?

Comment: Why not just create a branch?

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, that is what my answer uses. A dedicated branch, visible from the master branch as a subfolder (through a submodule declaration)

Comment: @VonC Why so complicated? A simple branch is enough.

Comment: check `git submodule` or `git subtree`

Comment: @MarekR Yes, submodule is what I use in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the branch `orhf-branch` of your own repository as a submodule in your master branch.

For an example of such a technique, see "[What's the easiest way to deploy a folder to a branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309)".

As a submodule, `my_notes.txt` would be visible in a subfolder (say '`orhf`') which is the root folder of the submodule.
Yet, any change/new commit made in the `master` branch would be separate from the  `orhf_branch`.

Any changes you are making in the `orhf_branch` and pushing, can be updated in any clone with a `git submodule update --remote`.

Comment: Only if you save the actual file elsewhere (such as in a submodule), though. You can make a symbolic link from `./my_notes.txt` to `orhf/my_notes.txt` to make this more convenient. You must also be aware of the pain of submodules (this is considerably reduced from early days of Git though).

Comment: To be  clearer: it is possible, without having to "delegate files" to a separate repository. It can be the same repo, as long as those files can exist in their own folder. I would avoid any symlink.

Comment: Well, sort of: if you make the submodule repository link to the original repository, it should all work. It's a little confusing, though.

Comment: It is also an old technique used from *years* (2008: http://blog.blindgaenger.net/generate_github_pages_in_a_submodule.html)

Comment: Interesting. I had not come across this idea before. I think I may just delete my answer, since this is a much less annoying technique than a separate repository...

Comment: The idea is: a submodule is *not always* a separate repository, indeed. It (the submodule) can follow a branch of the same repo.

Comment: @VonC This is a very interesting idea, thank you! I need some time to figure it out and try. 
Perhaps I did not formulate the question very precisely. There are many branches in the repository besides `master`, will the `orph` directory be present in all branches, or only in the `master` branch?

Comment: @WildZyzop Adding a submodule is like adding a file: that file will be in all branches only if you merge them. If not, you need to add it separately in each branch.