# How can I add the commits of a branch (e.g. rebase) onto two other primary branches?

Tags: python, git

Suppose I have two branches of a Python application, `threads` that uses the `threading` module, and `process` that uses the `multiprocessing` module. These two branches differ only with respect to how they execute concurrent tasks.

Now, say I create another branch `feature`. How can I add the commits of `feature` to both `threads` and `process`, so that `threads` and `process` stay up-to-date and include the same features?

Comment: What VCS you are using ?  Git ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar - Git, yes.

Answer (score 1):

IF that feature branch involves files in a subfolder, then you might consider include that branch content (assuming said branch only includes the files needed for said feature) as a submodule in those two branches.

[I used to do that for `gh-pages` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309), submodule in the `master` branch of a GitHub repo for instance.

But if not, if the feature branch is most of the `threads` or `process` branch files plus some modification, then you would need to merge that `feature` branch twice, to `threads` and to `process` branches.

Comment: thank you. I’m relatively new to Git. Is it an anti-pattern what I’m trying to do, or is it normal in development? So, to understand your answer correctly, I should merge `feature` with both `threads` and `process`. Rebasing would not be possible here for a nicer looking commit history?

Comment: @Shuzheng What is not a good pattern is having two branches with only minor differences. Ideally, that difference is part of one common code, with an option set to use threads or process "mode". That way, you avoid the all "double-merge" part.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying @Shuzheng. I am writing what I understood from your question and my response after that.

**What I understood from your question :**

1. I have a branch `thread`.
2. I have a branch `process`.
3. Now I create a new branch `feature` that I am going to use for development.

--> It is not clear `feature` branch was created from what source/base.

**Here is how I would deal with this issue -**

1. Develop on `feature` branch and make code changes there.
2. Once the feature is developed I would `git merge` branch `feature` into `thread` and `process`.
3. There could be some `merge-conflicts` arising when I do it for the first time. But from 2nd time onwards if we maintain this process, it would be very simple 1 minute job.

This is like pulling the changes done in `feature` branch into other 2 branches.

Also, I would suggest to use some IDE for doing this as it makes visualization very easy during merging.

Comment: Yes, merging into both branches is exactly what my answer illustrate.