# Copying content of a directory on another branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-branch, git-checkout

I have 2 branches on github:

- `master`
- `gh-pages`

My branch `master` has the directory `_site` which contains all the files that I need to be stored on the root of `gh-pages`.

I am using the git command:
`git checkout master -- _site`

To copy the contents of `_site` to the `gh-pages` branch.

My issue is that I am getting the directory and it's content while I need the content only on the root.

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the problem of making a copy of the folder, then checkout a new branch and copy over the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set gh-pages as submodule of your own repository.

That means adding the`gh-pages` branch content as a subfolder of your current repository, in the `master` branch, using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).
(unless, as explained here, you [chose the `master` branch itself as source for GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309))

```
git checkout master
git submodule add -b gh-pages -- /remote/url/of/your/own/repo gh-pages
git commit -m "Add gh-pages branch as submodule"
git push
```

You will have a `gh-pages` subfolder, that you can update at any time with:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

> My issue is that I am getting the directory and it's content while I need the content only on the root.

You would generate, from your main repository, the site content not in the directory `_site`, but in the directory `gh-pages` (which would thereforce have directly the site content).