# Build into gh-pages branch from master branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

What I want to do:
I am using github.
I have two branches. Master and gh-pages.
I have a unity3d project on my master branch. When I run it, it will generate a webpage.
I want to display the contents of the webpage on the gh-pages branch.

I assume this means I have to share a folder between two branches of my repository.
That seems nearly impossible.

Is there a right way to do this? My current solution is making two github projects and building from the first into the second. Then, I view the gh-page for the second. That seems very... extraneous. I should be able to do this all with one project.

Comment: O.o that's a very strange situation... I would have handled the web pages on a different branch from those 2.

Comment: I don't expect to be doing this for too long. Sooner or later, the game will get its own website, but for now being able to hit build/commit and have it host without any other funny business would be wonderful.

Comment: Here's something that works: "git checkout master WebPlayer/WebPlayer.unity3d". Run that from gh-pages and it will pull in the web player. Now, can I automate git to run that script just before I commit gh-pages, every time?

Comment: Ok. There's this thing called a git-hook. If I do... something... I can get the above script to run every time I switch to the gh-pages branch. Unfortunately, I have very little idea what that something is. My current plan is to: 1) go into ".git/hooks" and create "post-checkout.bat" (I'm on windows, would bat make sense or is it .txt or .sh?). Then, I put the script in the bat file and, when I switch to gh-pages, it copies over the file I want. Only, it doesn't. Any advise?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590156/git-update-the-root-directory-of-a-branch-from-the-subdirectory-of-another/10591668#10591668)

Answer (score 11):

You can just clone your repository *again* within your working directory structure of the first repository. So locally, you have this folder structure:

```
project
|- .git/
|- .gitignore
|- (other project related files)
|- deploy/
   |- .git/
   |- (deployed files)
```

Both `project` and `deploy` are cloned repositories of your project; `deploy` has the `gh-pages` branch checked out. The outer `.gitignore` obviously lists `deploy/`, so the folder is ignored for the project.

Now, when deploying, you publish all the files into the deploy folder, then cd into it, do a `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push` and the generated files are deployed.

Obviously this will not give you an actual relation between your master and the gh-pages branch, but both will live completely independent of each other in the same repository.

Comment: This is discussed in a [relatively popular gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/825950).

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the Jekyll workflow. Say unity3d content is generated into a folder called `foo`. Add `foo` to `.gitignore` then do this

```
git checkout master
<run unity3d>
git checkout gh-pages
git rm -qr .
cp -r foo/. .
rm -r foo
git add
git commit
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/jekyll-publish.sh)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the fantastically awesome [gh-pages](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages) npm module.  With a few lines of code, eg:

```
var ghpages = require('gh-pages');
var path = require('path');
ghpages.publish(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), function(err) { ... });
```

You will be create the gh-pages branch, and push it to github!

In more detail, from the docs:

> Calling this function will create a temporary clone of the current repository, create a `gh-pages` branch if one doesn't already exist, copy over all files from the base path, or only those that match patterns from the optional `src` configuration, commit all changes, and push to the `origin` remote.

It is super configurable, and works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to push my doxygen docs from master to gh-pages "easily."

I read similar solutions and my eyes glazed over.

My solution was:

1. source branch: have the files a .gitignore listed "temporary directory"
2. change branches to gh-pages (which preserves the .gitignore listed directory)
3. gh-pages branch: rsync from the temporary directory to the proper directory
4. gh-pages branch: 'git add -u' the proper location directory
5. gh-pages branch: 'git commit'

This still requires manually running the update and committing, which might be a good thing if you are posting to the website only from specific builds.

Example (mostly comments) at: https://github.com/nekenyu/libBsdSockets/blob/gh-pages/update_doc.sh