# Is there a way to use a pre/post commit hook in github to update gh-pages branch from master?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a completely static site (eg. https://github.com/robertjchristian/angular-enterprise-seed) hosted on [github](https://github.com/robertjchristian/angular-enterprise-seed), where I work mostly out of the master branch.  The contents of the /app/ directory are byte-for-byte what I want to host.  So during development I just cd ~/projects/angular-enterprise-seed/app, and then "python -m SimpleHTTPServer".  This allows me to browse the site locally at localhost:8000.

I want to host the static contents of /app on the web as well, and gh-pages is the ideal candidate.  Here are my requirements:

- Don't want to "just use gh-pages branch as master"
- Don't want to rely on a wrapper script that keeps gh-pages in line with master changes from the client.
- Don't want to build out a service to handle the webhook post, checkout from master, and check into gh-pages.

Ideally it would be a github hook that says "Post commit hook - sync gh-pages with change in master"

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a site that does exactly this but (a) can't find it now, and (b) it's in alpha and doesn't work yet.  I ended up putting a bash script on PythonAnywhere.com and scheduling a 24 hr job that pulls master and updates gh-pages with the section containing the static site.  Works like a charm and took ten minutes to setup.

Comment: care to share that script?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411849/push-local-master-into-gh-pages-branch-on-github) [variety](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907038/build-into-gh-pages-branch-from-master-branch) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705224/github-how-to-include-files-from-master-in-new-git-branch-gh-pages) [solutions](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/825950) for handling the [sync](http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/easily-keep-gh-pages-in-sync-with-master/) between [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807459/github-mirroring-gh-pages-to-master) and gh-pages, I ended up adopting an approached favored by JavaScript guru [Sindre Sorhus](https://twitter.com/sindresorhus) and others:

1. Make the gh-pages branch the default one on GitHub
2. [Delete the master branch](http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/#deleting-master)
3. Use the `gh-pages` branch as master.

You can see this on GitHub in Sindre's [screenful.js repo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), or in my project, [selection-menu](https://github.com/iDoRecall/selection-menu).