# Git rebase is not producing fast-forwardable commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

So I've been trying to use the following `post-commit` hook to keep my `gh-pages` branch up to date with master:

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout gh-pages
git rebase master
git checkout master
```

Per suggestion [here](http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/)

Here is some output from my git `lg` command which is this (I found it somewhere here on SO, thanks whoever posted it)

```
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

It produces a nice readable dump in the terminal:

```
*   463703d - (HEAD, gh-pages) Merge branch 'gh-pages' of github.com:unphased/ply into gh-pages (2 minutes ago) <Ste
|\  
| *   ef1a304 - (origin/gh-pages) Merge branch 'gh-pages' of github.com:unphased/ply into gh-pages (8 minutes ago) <
| |\  
| | *   2d0c8a1 - Merge branch 'gh-pages' of github.com:unphased/ply into gh-pages (26 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
| | |\  
| | | *   840df78 - Merge branch 'master' into gh-pages (68 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
| | | |\  
| | | * \   7db37cc - Merge branch 'master' into gh-pages (7 hours ago) <Steven Lu>
| | | |\ \  
| | | * | | 17f3dbc - Create gh-pages branch via GitHub (24 hours ago) <Steven Lu>
| | |  / /  
| | * | | 48bdf22 - Create gh-pages branch via GitHub (31 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
| * | | | d15c161 - Create gh-pages branch via GitHub (9 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
* | | | | 7024a62 - Create gh-pages branch via GitHub (4 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
* | | | | f61b62d - (master) hopefully stuff calms down (4 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
|/ / / /  
* | | | 05c26a5 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD) some more progress (9 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
|/ / /  
* | | 20c6bdb - some progess on the touchmove event handler finally. hopefully this one will run the post-commit hoo
* | | d1ab53e - commented out touchmove log.. testing the auto-rebase on gh-pages (45 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
| |/  
|/|   
* | 15fe88d - small update to js (70 minutes ago) <Steven Lu>
|/  
* 6b5ee18 - updating note about mutation events' (7 hours ago) <Steven Lu>
* 1b43564 - okay now about ready to start assembling offsets. [snip]
```

The rest of the history is pretty uninteresting ([here](https://github.com/unphased/ply/network) is a github network graph representation which may be somewhat less headachy), and I was hoping to keep the new bits (the updating of `gh-pages`) to also be uninteresting, but it is clear to me right now that there are a buttload of non-fast-forward merges that are happening that shouldn't be happening if `rebase` is correctly occurring.

So, since I have absolutely no idea where to even begin diagnosing the problem of what goes wrong when the rebase happens I'll show you the output of the last time I committed, which produced this (I commit to `master`):

```
$ git commit -a -m"hopefully stuff calms down"
Switched to branch 'gh-pages'
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
gApplying: Create gh-pages branch via GitHub
iApplying: Create gh-pages branch via GitHub
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:985: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:1019: trailing whitespace.
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
<stdin>:1020: trailing whitespace.
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
<stdin>:1031: trailing whitespace.
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
<stdin>:1055: trailing whitespace.
  line-height: 1.5; 
warning: squelched 27 whitespace errors
warning: 32 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Applying: Create gh-pages branch via GitHub
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:985: trailing whitespace.

<stdin>:1019: trailing whitespace.
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
<stdin>:1020: trailing whitespace.
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
<stdin>:1031: trailing whitespace.
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
<stdin>:1055: trailing whitespace.
  line-height: 1.5; 
warning: squelched 27 whitespace errors
warning: 32 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
[master f61b62d] hopefully stuff calms down
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Out of the many things here that look out of the ordinary one i'm curious about is why commits labeled with "Create gh-pages branch via GitHub" keep getting added. That is indeed the most up to date commit on the `gh-pages` branch and which presumably gets re-appended upon performing the `rebase`, but the issue seems to be that something is causing the requirement of merging when they should be fast-forwards.

I am pretty sure that if I've got this right that using rebase I can produce a log where each commit to master is duplicated in gh-pages (rather than using merge where a merge commit is created in gh-pages for each commit in master), but right now I have to do merging without rebasing or I get this unholy mess.

Comment: A rebase in a post-commit hook seems like a terrible idea. Why would you want this and why would you think it would always make fast-forwardable commits?

Comment: Like I said I'm not sure: it's pretty clear that I'm not supposed to rebase an already-pushed branch. So I have no idea why people would suggest to have this be the method to keep `gh-pages` up to date. I had simply assumed that these people making the blog posts know what they are doing.

Comment: Here's where I found the advice: http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/1084945) might be where you found the `alias`, in case you were looking for it. :)

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559917/git-rebase-and-git-push-non-fast-forward-why-use) is probably relevant. If `gh-pages` is always *behind* `master` (that is, a `merge` of `master` **into** `gh-pages` will always be a `fast-forward` merge), perhaps changing the hook to `merge` rather than `rebase` would work.

Comment: Could the original `rebase` workflow work if I was doing my work in the `gh-pages` branch instead? But I think that means the command would have to be `git rebase gh-pages` from the `master` branch instead. Makes no sense.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10591668/1290731) (it's mine) might be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the comments! I hope someone can elaborate on where the suggestion to do this rebase process post-commit to master fails. Because it clearly fails to do a reasonable thing for me. At first I assumed it is because I had done something wrong setting things up. But maybe that isn't the case. So then I don't get why Lea Verou, Oli and Paul Irish seem to think it's a good idea to use `rebase`. And also, @jthill, your answer might work but it looks so enigmatic to me that I don't dare run it.