# Git workflow with different file tree on each branches

Tags: git, merge, workflow

I have some git repos where the branches don't have the same file tree. Example:

- dev branch: src and dist folders on root
- live branch: dist content on root

For now, the "best" workflow I have found is (when I want to "merge" dev branch on to live branch):

- git checkout live (from dev)
- git checkout dev dist/
- git reset HEAD *
- copy/paste content of the dist folder on root and delete it
- git add & commit

As I'm not a git pro, I was wondering if there is a best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: update the root directory of a branch from the subdirectory of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590156/git-update-the-root-directory-of-a-branch-from-the-subdirectory-of-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "copy/paste content of the dist folder on root and delete it" I gather you're not merging changes from both sides but simply updating to the new version.  If that's correct,

```
git checkout live
git read-tree -um HEAD: dev:dist     # fast-forward current tree to dev's dist
git rev-parse dev >.git/MERGE_HEAD   # tell porcelain this is a merge
git commit                           # record it
```

will do it.  [`read-tree -m` with two trees](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_two_tree_merge) produces a fast-forward merge from the first to the second, and `-u` means to update the worktree with the results.  You're going from the checked-out tree to the `dev` branch's current `dist` tree, and this is the correct result of merging from `dev`, so recording it as a merge is correct.

But since you're fast-forwarding, the result will be the new tree.  This is a dup of a question that's been asked many times before.  I confess I like my answer best:

```
git commit-tree -p gh-pages -p master -m "" master:html \
| xargs git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages
```

(update the names to taste), it just does what needs doing directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could track dist folder as a separate [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Instead of dev branch, you would have a different repo that includes it, and on live, you would need to check out just the dist repo alone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at git submodule. But I think I would prefer to keep all my branches on the same repo, otherwise it will double the number of my repos...

Comment: I had a look at git submodule but I'm not sure to understand what you are suggesting? Because if I understand well I will have a dist repo and a dev repo (instead of branches). And in the dev repo I will include the dist repo as submodule in a dist folder? If I do this, how can I keep track of my work on the dev repo to the dist repo?